# Specify NULLS LAST in @OrderBy of @OneToMany mapped Collection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, integration-testing, h2

I have a mapped entity like this:

```java
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Child.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "PARENT_ID")
@OrderBy("orderNumber")
private List<Child> children;
```

I would like to specify `NULLS LAST` in `@OrderBy` annotation of my mapped collection.

I am using Oracle database, which considers NULL values larger than any non-NULL values.
The problem is in my integration test, which uses h2 database and it seems the NULL values are evaluated differently.

So far, I came up with a hack to use `nvl2()` function inside of the `@OrderNumber` like this:

```java
@OrderBy("nvl2(orderNumber, orderNumber, 100000000)")
```

This hack works, but it seems nasty and I don't like the idea that I have this code there just because of the integration tests. As I mentioned above, Oracle returns the rows in correct order by default, so the basic `@OrderBy(orderNumber)` without handling nulls works good. On the other hand, I want to have it tested in case the app will use different database.

Is there any way how to solve this issue in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable Oracle compatibility mode in H2 you need to append `;MODE=Oracle;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH` to JDBC URL as suggested in documentation:
https://h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility

The [`DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING`](https://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_default_null_ordering) setting changes the default ordering of `NULL` values (when neither `NULLS FIRST` nor `NULLS LAST` are used). There are four possible options, `LOW` is default.

This setting can be used separately without this compatibility mode if you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you, it seems legit. Now I only need to find out where is the JDBC URL specified as for the testing environment, we have separate JTA datasource called ExampleDS, but I couldn't find it in the standalone.xml.